# use local docker image on gcloud build submit

Tags: docker, gcloud

I am trying to use `gcloud builds submit` with local docker image. The reason why i need to do is Dockerfile needs to access private registry, so i need to build docker image first. Here is the steps i do.

1. build docker image

   docker build -t build-image .

   docker tag build-image:latest $GCP_IMAGE_URL
2. then run `gcloud builds submit --tag $GCP_IMAGE_URL`. I also tried with '.'

It looks like gcloud tries to rebuild the image, so that the process fails since it can not access private registry. is it possible to run `gcloud builds submit` with local docker image?

Answer (score 0):

spent hours to find the way to make it works.

my understading is that `gcloud builds submit` does not support local image, it builds an image on cloud.

so what to do:

1. once you have local docker image, need to push it to artifact registry manually by run following command

   gcloud auth configure-docker your-region-docker.pkg.dev

   docker push $GCP_IMAGE_URL
2. run `gcloud run deploy` with your options